# Uploading files from Azure Blob Storage to SFTP location using Databricks?

Tags: python, scala, azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a scenario where I need to copy files from `Azure Blob Storage` to `SFTP` location in `Databricks`

Is there a way to achieve this scenario using `pySpark` or `Scala`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following steps (I use scala)

1. Mount Azure Blob storage containers to DBFS

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  mountPoint = "/mnt/blob",
  extraConfigs = Map("fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net" -> "<key>"))

dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/blob")
```

[image]

2. Copy these file to clusters local file system

```
%sh

cp -R /dbfs/mnt/blob  /databricks/driver
ls -R /databricks/driver/blob
```

[image]

3. Code. Before running the code, please add library`com.jcraft.jsch` vai Maven in databricks

```
import java.io.File
import scala.sys.process._
import com.jcraft.jsch._
def recursiveListFiles(f: File): Array[File] = {
  val these = f.listFiles
  these ++ these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(recursiveListFiles)
}
val jsch = new JSch()
val session = jsch.getSession("<usename>", "<host>",<port>) // Set your username and host
session.setPassword("<password>") // Set your password
val config = new java.util.Properties()
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
session.setConfig(config)
session.connect()
val channelSftp = session.openChannel("sftp").asInstanceOf[ChannelSftp]
channelSftp.connect()

val files =recursiveListFiles(new File("/databricks/driver/blob"))

files.foreach(file =>{

  if(file.isFile()){
    println(file.getPath())
    channelSftp.put(file.getPath(),"/home/testqw/upload")
  }
     
  

})
channelSftp.disconnect()
session.disconnect()
```

[image]

4. Check with [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php)

---

#Update

After we mount Azure blob, we can directly access file and upload it.

For example

```
import java.io.File
import scala.sys.process._
import com.jcraft.jsch._
def recursiveListFiles(f: File): Array[File] = {
  val these = f.listFiles
  these ++ these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(recursiveListFiles)
}
val jsch = new JSch()
val session = jsch.getSession("", "",22) // Set your username and host
session.setPassword("") // Set your password
val config = new java.util.Properties()
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
session.setConfig(config)
session.connect()
val channelSftp = session.openChannel("sftp").asInstanceOf[ChannelSftp]
channelSftp.connect()
val home = channelSftp.getHome()

val files =recursiveListFiles(new File("/dbfs/mnt/blob"))

files.foreach(file =>{

  if(file.isFile()){
    println(file.getPath())
    channelSftp.put(file.getPath(),"/home/testqw/upload")
  }
     
  

})
channelSftp.disconnect()
session.disconnect()
```

[image]

Comment: @DipanjanMallick  If we use `com.jcraft.jsch` to upload file, we cannot access file  from mounted location. If you want to access file from mounted location, we only can read file with spark, then we can use the spark sftp connector to upload file. But it has some limitations. We should use spark 2.x and scala 2.1.1 : https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp

Comment: Thanks @Jim Xu for the update....Not sure on that front! As I'm able to upload the files directly from the mounted location

Comment: @DipanjanMallickd Could you please tell me how you do that?

Comment: I just replaced /databricks/driver/ with /dbfs/mnt/blob  as below val files =recursiveListFiles(new File(" /dbfs/mnt/blob"))

Comment: @DipanjanMallick Thanks for your sharing. If your issue has been resolved, could you please accept it as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for your extensive reply! Question, do you know how to modify your solution if there is a proxy to be connected to first? Spring ML does not support proxy